# Test Auth0 Login with RSpec in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, rspec, auth0

I'm using [Auth0](https://auth0.com/) for authentication in my rails app. I need to write some feature tests for login and signup. I can't seem to find something concrete on how to do this with rspec and capybara.

Tried doing something along the lines explained in this [gist](https://gist.github.com/kinopyo/1338738) but it still doesn't work. If someone has had experience with rspec feature tests with Auth0 I'd appreciate if you would guide me in the right direction.

Thanks!

My configuration

```
# in spec/support/omniauth_macros.rb
module OmniauthMacros
  def mock_auth_hash
    # The mock_auth configuration allows you to set per-provider (or default)
    # authentication hashes to return during integration testing.
    OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:auth0] = {
      'provider' => 'auth0',
      'uid' => '123545',
      'user_info' => {
        'name' => 'mockuser',
        'image' => 'mock_user_thumbnail_url'
      },
      'credentials' => {
        'token' => 'mock_token',
        'secret' => 'mock_secret'
      }
    }
  end
end

# in spec/requests/spec_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...
  # include our macro
  config.include(OmniauthMacros)
end

OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true
```

Then in my spec I have

```
   scenario 'Should successfully login user' do
       visit login_path

       mock_auth_hash
       click_link "Sign in"

      expect(page).to have_content('Signed in successfully')
      expect(page).to have_link("Logout", href: logout_path)
    end
```

Comment: Use the same steps as in the gist but use `OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:auth0]`. As written this question is off topic for a number of reasons - you are asking for a tutorial or an off site reference, and this question is very open ended and cannot be answered in an authoritative way.

Answer (score 6):

This is how I solved it

```
# in spec/support/omniauth_macros.rb
module OmniauthMacros
  def mock_valid_auth_hash(user)
    # The mock_auth configuration allows you to set per-provider (or default)
    # authentication hashes to return during integration testing.
    opts = {
        "provider": user.provider,
        "uid": user.uid,
        "info": {
            "email": user.email,
            "first_name": user.first_name,
            "last_name": user.last_name,
        },
        "credentials": {
            "token": "XKLjnkKJj7hkHKJkk",
            "expires": true,
            "id_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJK1VveHkwaTFBNXdTek41dXAiL.Wz8bwniRJLQ4Fqx_omnGDCX1vrhHjzw",
            "token_type": "Bearer"
        }
    }
    OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:auth0] =  OmniAuth::AuthHash.new(opts)
  end

  def mock_invalid_auth_hash
    OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[:auth0] = :invalid_credentials
  end
end

# in spec/support/features/session_helpers.rb
module Features
  module SessionHelpers

    def log_in(user, invalid=false, strategy = :auth0)
      invalid ?  mock_invalid_auth_hash : mock_valid_auth_hash(user)
      Rails.application.env_config["omniauth.auth"] = OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[strategy.to_sym]
      visit "/auth/#{strategy.to_s}/callback?code=vihipkGaumc5IVgs"
    end
  end
end

# in spec/support/rails_helper.rb
RSpec.configure do |config|
  # ...
  # include our macro
  config.include(OmniauthMacros)

  # include Session helpers
  config.include Features::SessionHelpers, type: :feature
end
```

And finally my feature test to simulate login looks like

```
# user signin feature test

require 'rails_helper'

feature 'Login with Omniauth' do
  given(:user) { create(:user) }

  context "With valid credentials" do
    scenario 'Should successfully login user' do
      log_in(user)

      expect(page).to have_content("successfully signed in")
      expect(page).to have_link("Logout", href: logout_path)
    end
  end

  context "With invalid credentials" do
    scenario "Should not log in user" do
      log_in(user, true)
      expect(page).to have_content('invalid_credentials')
    end
  end
end
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I had to change `OmniAuth.config.mock_auth[strategy.to_sym]` to `OmniAuth.config.mock_auth` and add an `app/views/auth0/failure.html.erb` file due to `OmniAuth::Strategies::OAuth2::CallbackError, csrf_detected | CSRF detected`

Comment: To add to this, make sure that in the `spec/support/rails_helper.rb`  or in your `environment/config/test.rb` file you include this line from the gist
```OmniAuth.config.test_mode = true```

Comment: I added onto this feature with a logout method also, as it wouldn't automatically logout users through sessions, and added some flavor around building the same for feature and request specs. 

https://captaincole.build/articles/testing-auth0-with-rspec-and-capybara